# Capacitor diode circuit

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, diodes

I have this circuit

[image]

My task is to match these four statements.

1. "\$v_1=0\$ for a very long time. The time constant for the charging time for the  capacitor immediately after \$v_1\$ jumps to \$v_1=10V\$ is ...
2. "\$v_1=10V\$ for a very long time. The time constant for the discharge time for the capacitor immediately after \$v_1\$ jumps to \$v_1=0\$ is ...
3. \$R_2\cdot C\$
4. \$(R_1+R_2)\cdot C\$

I can't really find any arguments as to why these statements belong together.

Has it something to do with the diodes not being forward biased? I hope someone can clarify this for me.

**Edit**

The main problem I have with this, is that I don't exactly understand how the capacitor is charging and discharging through the resistors, and when and why the diodes are conducting and non-conducting.

I just saw the answers to this problem. For number 1 they have this drawing.

[image]

For number 2 they have this drawing.

[image]

Comment: You should match "question" 1 with "answer" 3 or "answer" 4 and "question" 2 with the remaining "answer" (answer 3 or answer 4)

Comment: *Has it something to do with the diodes not being forward biased?* So all the diodes are in reverse mode? Are you sure? Consider the cases where C has no charge and V1 is 1) a negative voltage 2) V1 = 0 V and 3) When V1 = a positive voltage.

Comment: Huisman, can you please explain why this is?

Comment: There are other relations as well: All four statements relate to each other because they all address the same circuit. Statement 3 and 4 relate because the only consist of component value variables. But assuming this is a homework assignment, I think my first comment makes most sense.

Comment: Do you understand that V1 either changes from 0V to 10V, or from 10V to 0V, and you have to align these two conditions with the time constants given in 3. and 4.?

Comment: I have edited the original question.

Comment: As this is homework, another hint: is when a voltage source is turned down to zero volts, it behaves like a short circuit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A diode is **only** conducting when its anode side has a higher voltage than its cathode side.

So you can think of it as a one-way street for current, where current can only flow in the direction of the arrow symbol of the diode.

This is why you have two different current paths for charging and decharging of the capacitor and thus two different time constants.